# Insert different tables from a while loop in a temporary table

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem coding in `SQL Server`, I'm trying to create a temporary table where I stored different tables created inside a while loop, the problem is that it only stored the first table, but then when start the second loop it breaks and give the error:

> (9267 row(s) affected)
>       Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 16
>       There is already an object named '##EPIF_2010_2016' in the database.

Mi code is:

```
DECLARE @MES INT
DECLARE @AÑO INT
SET @MES=01
SET @AÑO=2010

WHILE 

CAST(@AÑO AS VARCHAR) + CASE WHEN LEN(@MES)<2 THEN '0' + CAST(@MES AS VARCHAR(2)) 
ELSE + CAST(@MES AS VARCHAR(2))END <=
CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + CASE WHEN LEN(MONTH(GETDATE()))<2 THEN'0'+CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()-1) AS VARCHAR(2)) 
ELSE +cast(MONTH(GETDATE()-1) AS VARCHAR(2))END

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(CART.Producto_Poliza) AS VOLUMEN, 
SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT,REPLACE(CART.[Prima mensual],',','.'))) AS PRIMA_MENSUAL,
(CAST(@MES AS NVARCHAR(2))+'-01-'+CAST(@AÑO AS NVARCHAR(4))) AS [Inicio de Vigencia],
CART.[Descripción de la fuente],CART.[Descripción de la campaña], PROD.PROD_DESCRIPTION, SE.SubPlan
INTO ##EPIF_2010_2016
FROM CARTERA_DICIEMBRE_2016 CART
LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_NEWPRODUCTSIISMX PROD ON PROD.PRODUCT_ID = CART.[Número del producto]
LEFT OUTER JOIN SENumber SE ON SE.[SE number] = CART.[Numero de Afiliación]

WHERE CAST(YEAR([Inicio de Vigencia])AS VARCHAR)+CASE WHEN LEN (MONTH([Inicio de Vigencia]))<2 
THEN '0'+CAST(MONTH([Inicio de Vigencia])AS VARCHAR) 
ELSE +CAST(MONTH([Inicio de Vigencia])AS VARCHAR)
END <= 
CAST(@AÑO as VARchar)+CASE WHEN LEN (@MES)<2 THEN '0'+CAST(@MES AS VARCHAR(2)) 
ELSE +cast(@MES AS VARCHAR(2))END
AND (CAST(YEAR([Fecha Cancelación])AS VARCHAR)+ CASE WHEN LEN (MONTH([Fecha Cancelación]))<2 
THEN '0'+CAST(MONTH([Fecha Cancelación])AS VARCHAR) 
ELSE +CAST(MONTH([Fecha Cancelación])AS VARCHAR)END > 
CAST(@AÑO as VARchar)+CASE WHEN LEN (@MES)<2 
THEN '0'+CAST(@MES AS VARCHAR(2)) 
ELSE +cast(@MES AS VARCHAR(2))END
OR [Fecha Cancelación] IS NULL)

GROUP BY CART.[Inicio de Vigencia],CART.[Descripción de la fuente],CART.[Descripción de la campaña],
PROD.PROD_DESCRIPTION,SE.SubPlan

SET @AÑO= CASE WHEN @MES=12 THEN @AÑO+1
ELSE @AÑO END
SET @MES= CASE WHEN @MES<12 THEN @MES+1 
WHEN @MES=12 THEN 1 END

END;
```

Is there any function like `INSERT INTO`, in this case, that insert every new table in my temporary table ##EPIF_2010_2016?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course it does. You are using select into which will create the table with the name you provide. The table will already exist when you try to run the insert statement again. You really should avoid loops for this type of thing and instead use a set based insert. You have a number of coding issues in here too. Like varchar with no length, and the formatting makes me want take out my eyeballs and pop them.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use your loop, you need to create the temp table and then use `insert into ##...`

```
create table ##epif_2010_2016 (
  volumen bigint
, prima_mensual float
, [Inicio de Vigencia] date
, [Descripción de la fuente]  nvarchar(256)
, [Descripción de la campaña] nvarchar(256)
, prod_description nvarchar(256)
, SubPlan nvarchar(256)
)

while ..... 
begin
insert into ##epif_2010_2016 (
    volumen
  , prima_mensual float
  , [Inicio de Vigencia] 
  , [Descripción de la fuente] 
  , [Descripción de la campaña]
  , prod_description
  , SubPlan
  )
  select...
```

You don't need to use a loop at all. You can do this as a set based operation with the help of a months table/subquery/common table expression:

```
declare @fromdate date = '20100101';
declare @thrudate date = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @mydate)-1, 0);

;with Months as (
select top (datediff(month,@fromdate,@thrudate)+1)
      [Month] = dateadd(month
                , row_number() over (order by number) -1
                , @StartDate)
  from master.dbo.spt_values
)

select 
    volumen=count(cart.Producto_Poliza)
  , prima_mensual= sum(convert(float, replace(cart.[Prima mensual], ',', '.'))) 
  , [Inicio de Vigencia] = m.[Month]
  , cart.[Descripción de la fuente]
  , cart.[Descripción de la campaña]
  , prod.prod_description
  , se.SubPlan
  into ##epif_2010_2016
 from cartera_diciembre_2016 as cart
  inner join Months as m 
    on cart.[Inicio de Vigencia] <= m.Month
    and (cart.[Fecha Cancelación] > m.Month
        or cart.[Fecha Cancelación] is null)
  left join tbl_newproductsiismx as prod 
    on prod.product_id = cart.[Número del producto]
  left join senumber as se 
    on se.[se number] = cart.[Numero de Afiliación]
 group by 
    cart.[Inicio de Vigencia]
  , cart.[Descripción de la fuente]
  , cart.[Descripción de la campaña]
  , prod.prod_description
  , se.SubPlan;
```